# Dates on timeline have disappeared

Tags: java, swing, plugins, jfreechart

First read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645117/jstockchart-drag-around-graph) I just posted.

Regardless from that question, I have another question.

In the result from my program:[image]

I don't get any dates at the lower horizontal axis like the jstockchart demo has:

[image]

I also saw that [somebody commented on the demo](https://code.google.com/p/jstockchart/wiki/JStockChartGettingStarted) (at the bottom) that they were also not able to reproduce this.

I know the code for attaching times to the axis is the following:

```
// Specifies date axis ticks.
private static LogicDateAxis createlogicDateAxis(Date baseDate) {
    LogicDateAxis logicDateAxis = new LogicDateAxis(baseDate,
            new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("09:30", TickAlignment.START);
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("10:00");
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("10:30");
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("11:00");
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("11:30", TickAlignment.END);
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("13:00", TickAlignment.START);
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("13:30");
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("14:00");
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("14:30", TickAlignment.END);
    logicDateAxis.addDateTick("15:00", TickAlignment.END);
    return logicDateAxis;
}
```

But why doesn't it show up?

All the code can be found [in my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645117/jstockchart-drag-around-graph). Thanks in advance.