# Extend JFreeChart series x-values to be equal to other series

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am currently experimenting with JFreeChart and have a problem.
I use a TimeSeries chart with 2 different series which have different x-values.

Now I want JFreeChart to let both graphs start at the same x-value and end at the same x-value, depending on which of the series starts earlier or ends later. So that both graphs have the same length.

Is this easily possible or do I have to manipulate the series?

Greetings
FloFri

Comment: Have you tried a second axis like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13560964/261156)?

Comment: The x-axis is not the problem, this is the same for both series, but the x-range of each series is different (like one series from 1 to 3 and one from 2 to 4, so I want both series to extend to 1 to 4)

Comment: That sounds confusing. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.